# EJB3 Interceptors for logging

Tags: ejb-3.0, interceptor

In an MDB application, Can the EJB3 Interceptor be configured to log the Non bean class methods, which are inturn invoked by the bean method (OnMessage)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, EJB interceptors are only applicable to business methods.  For non-business methods, you need to use an aspect-oriented programming technology.